Errors when cloning flutter app from GitHub
I encountered an issue when cloning the Flutter app from GitHub to VS code editor.
When I run Git:clone and copy the path of a flutter app, the app can be opened in VS code. However, there exist a lot of errors in the file, especially on the import lines (the number of errors is more than hundreds, almost all the lines are red).

just run Flutter Pub get and error solved.

When you clone a repository, you need to install dependencies like you do with  others platforms, npm installl for example.
To achieve this in Flutter, you need to issue the command flutter pub get in project root directory.
This will install dependencies.
